# I can't retrieve single list item from SharePoint using JSOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-jsom

I am querying a SharePoint 2010 list using caml and JSOM.  My query will always return 1 item but when I remove the While() loop, nothing happens.  Any help would  be much appreciated.

```
function retrieveListItems() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project');


    var prjQry = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='tID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + getQueryString('tID') + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Project_x0020_Number' /><FieldRef Name='Station_x0020_Name' /><FieldRef Name='VISN' /><FieldRef Name='Station_x0020_Number' /></ViewFields></View>";        

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(prjQry);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

             $('#visn').val(oListItem.get_item('VISN'));
            $('#projTitle').val(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
            $('#station').val(oListItem.get_item('Station_x0020_Number'));
            $('#stationName').val(oListItem.get_item('Station_x0020_Name'));                                                
           $('#projNumber').val(oListItem.get_item('Project_x0020_Number'));   
}              

}
```

Comment: I'm unclear about what you want help with. Does the above code work as expected for you?  If so, why do you want to remove the While loop?

Comment: Well, no item is being returned.  only 1 item gets returned so I was assuming it had something to do with using the while() loop

Comment: To clarify, is one item being returned or are no items being returned?

Comment: There is supposed to be one item returned but nothing is being returned.  When I remove the caml filter, items get returned.

Comment: That suggests there might be a problem with your CAML query. What type of field is tID, and are you certain of the field's internal name?

Comment: And did you try adding a reference to tID in the viewfields? it's probably not loaded in the context for the filtering query even if it exists

Comment: You are right Thriggle.  My CAML query was wrong. I was referencing the wrong field. It was supposed to be another field and not "tID".  Thanks!